# Visual Studio 2017, use new style csproj by default when creating new projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

Is there any way to use the new style csproj (with SDK, PackageReferences, and no need to use compile include etc.) by default when creating a new .net framework 4.5.2 project in Visual Studio?

At the moment I'm creating a .net standard project and then changing it to .net 4.5.2, or just manually changing the csproj, but even though this isn't that slow, I would rather it happen automatically obviously.

Old style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
...
```

New Style:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
...
```

Comment: I'm sad no one has answered this. I'd like to know, too.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc I would as well

Comment: What build of Visual Studio 2017 are you using, v15.7.4?

Comment: @PhillipNgan I am using 15.7.4

Comment: Not sure if it warrants an answer, but this tool can at least to it on CLI: https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017

Comment: @Lennart I was really hoping visual studio had some type of setting that would allow me to switch between the new project template and old project template. That tool is very useful though. I have been converting our companies projects by hand so that will definitely be useful.

Comment: Maybe MS is doing this to help push more devs to .net core/standard ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create new style .cproj by hand. After that you can export project template (Project->ExportTemplate)

[image: Export project template]

Specify project name, description and set checkbox 'Automatically import the template into Visual Studio'

[image: Select Template Options]

After that you can use this template in Visual Studio when creating new project
[image: Create New Project]

After project template have been created, you can customize them

[Customize project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-project-and-item-templates)

Comment: I have got this as an extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rubberduckdev.SDKStyleTemplatesNet might be helpful.